# Internal Server Error for Image Showing in ASP.Net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, image, webforms

Am trying to show upload pdf image in mysite using webforms control. Everything was ok except 1 pdf. Same code for other pdf is ok except this: -

Back Edn Code:

```
imgBrochure.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/cms") + rdrd["eventBrochure"].ToString().ToString().Replace("~/", "/") + "?width=500&pdfwidth=700";
```

My Front End Code:

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkAgendaSidebar" runat="server" class="text-center text-dark">
   <asp:Image ID="imgAgenda" runat="server" CssClass="img-fluid mb-3" /><br />
   <p class="font-weight-bold">Download Agenda</p>
 </asp:HyperLink>
```

After running project:

```
<a id="mainContent_lnkBrochureSidebar" class="text-center text-dark" download="Brochure-steel-conference-2018" href="/cms/uploads/event/brochure/2fc48237a69a4f77983eef542e6e70c7.pdf"><img id="mainContent_imgBrochure" class="img-fluid mb-3"src="/cms/uploads/event/brochure/2fc48237a69a4f77983eef542e6e70c7.pdf?width=500&amp;pdfwidth=700" /><br />
 <p class="font-weight-bold">Download Brochure</p>
                </a>
```

No issue about but as download link works properly but it's some issue for showing image & have to resize this. Need expert suggestion. Thanks

Comment: a pdf is not an image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue by my own. First resize/compress the pdf file before upload and change the front end to show those file image at front end. Previous code is ok just change this line of backend code

```
imgBrochure.ImageUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/cms") + rdrd["eventBrochure"].ToString().ToString().Replace("~/", "/") + "?w=1920&h=1200&mode=crop";
```

But someone has better suggestion then please let that here.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
 <a id="mainContent_lnkBrochureSidebar" class="text-center 

text-dark" download="Brochure-steel-conference-2018" 

href="/cms/uploads/event/brochure/2fc48237a69a4f77983eef5

42e6e70c7.pdf">
<embed src="file.pdf" width="500" 

height="375" 
 type='application/pdf'>
 <p class="font-weight-bold">Download Brochure</p>
                </a>
```

Comment: How I put this manually whether it generate code automatically from backend and gives internal server error.